# PDO exception error [database].semaphore doesnot exist

Tags: users, database, configuration

I created a website in drupal 7, tested it in my localhost and works good. Now, I want to host the site in our Main server. So, I uploaded the site directory to the server and created a corresponding database for that. Updated the settings.php file with the database name, user and password.

I do hope that the site install process is done. The site is deployed within the server, database created. When I give the address of the site, it shows some PDO exception error.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '[database].semaphore' doesn't exist: SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/cpath/D-6.12/apache2/htdocs/[htdocs]/includes/lock.inc).
```

I tried re-installing the drupal site, it didn't work.

I even reviewed and tried all the solutions shown in [drupal.org](http://drupal.org), but no way I couldn't resolve the issue.

I appreciate your valuable suggestions.

Comment: This question is duplicate. I already answered this in [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114656/drupal-pdoexception-when-creating-the-table/114671#114671). this is because of your database engine which must be converted to `MyISAM` from `InnoDB`. go to that link for more detail.

Comment: try running `update.php` [your-site]/update.php

Comment: I have gone through this post, but didn't dare to try it. Are you sure it works???

Comment: yes be sure. 98% of my website was completed and suddenly the same error reported. it took about one week to find the solution. just take a look at the comment below my answer. it worked for that guy too

Comment: update.php didn't work, same PDO exception error. But now the error was updated, [database].system does not exist 'code' in drupal_get_installed_schema_version() (line 155 of /home/cpath/D-6.12/apache2/htdocs/sehs/includes/install.inc). 'code'

Comment: try creating `semaphore table` on your database
**CREATE TABLE semaphore ( `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `expire` DOUBLE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (name), INDEX expire (expire) )**

Comment: hey, it didn't work man. I converted the database engine with MyISAM as you said. And even reflected the same changes in other databases within the directory. Other sites works fine, my site show the same error. NO CHANGE IN THE EXCEPTION.

Comment: did you change the drupal core? check your database to see if the `sepmaphore` is there. again export your DB to make sure that the engine is MyISAM

Comment: The error message is the same, but the scenario is different enough to not make this a dup.  This question is about a dev-to-live deployment, while the linked one is about a 6-to-7 upgrade.

Comment: What database server?  How did you take the backup?  How did you do the restore?  Are you positive that the semaphore table is in the backup?

Comment: @Drupalist :: drupal core?? why do we need to change the drupal core. I just changed the scheme.inc file in includes/databases/mysql/scheme.inc.. And the database : I created a new database after uploading the drupal site directory (within the server) and it is empty.

Comment: @GIRI by Drupal core I meant the `schema.inc`. why your DB is empty?! like I said export the old DB as `.sql` , open it in notepad or any text editor, look for `InnoDB` and replace it with `MyISAM` , save it. in the server `phpmyadmin` delete all the tables of the DB and import the new `.sql` file

Comment: @GIRI you welcome

Comment: can I know why InnoDB is not working?? heard it was a upgrade to MyISAM, then what was issue with it??

Comment: I don't know, but maybe it is because of some configuration in the server! it shouldn't be true because my website was working and it suddenly reported the error. anyway thanks to MyISAM

Comment: I suspect this solution is painting over a larger problem with the server.  My guess is that there is a configuration problem, or something is timing out w/ a silent error message.  Editing core files like this is never a good long term plan.  To be honest, I don't know how well tested Drupal 7 is anymore with MyISAM, so you may have problems under load, and other places where  proper transactions come into play.

Comment: @MPD Maybe you don't believe it but I saw the same error in Wordpress CMS and I solved it in the same way. Drupal 7 is totally compatible with MyISAM but I hope such thing doesn't occur in Drupal 8.

Comment: @Drupalist I have no doubt that this provided a solution for you.  The [Drupal 7 database requirements](https://drupal.org/requirements/database) do list MyISAM.  However, MyISAM does not support transactions, and the driver will silently skip any transaction requests.  This may cause problems under load, where transactions are needed for referential integrity, and also won't allow rollbacks to happen should an error occur during a transaction.  MyISAM is also not ACID compliant.  Problems with this may also only come out under load.

Comment: When you copy MySQL databases that are innoDB you need to copy the ib* files. Found explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260546/mysql-table-does-not-exist-error-but-it-does-exist

Answer (score 1):

Changing the database engine wont help.
What you should understand is what is drupal semaphores. follow this link: https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_sem if you want to understand what semaphores are. In you case it means this table of semaphores which drupal depends on does not exist due to your misconfiguration during migrate or install. You will have to run drupal install script.

However, semaphores tables dont run on innoDB but myISAM since its a PHP process that calls a third party service for data like drupal theme forms, theme tables ect.

I hope u understand.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error message in moving Drupal 7 from one development site to another development site on my laptop. Upon checking the tables in the Drupal database I found that the full sql dump was not being imported (using [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) and the "From server" option, adminer.sql).

Look for Drupal 7 database tables that come near the end of the dump alphabetically like:  **user***, **views***, **webform***, **workbench***, **xmlsitemap*** to see if it all imported.

I then used `drush sql-cli < database.sql` to import the sql dump into the Drupal database after dropping all tables with `drush sql-drop`.

Comment: Please don't double post answer across multiple questions. As the answer states, this is a duplicate question that should be flagged as such.

Comment: Sorry, I would have posted a comment and linked to the answer  on the other issue but since I do not have 50 points I cannot.