# Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown

Tags: 7, installation

I am trying to solve this issue from last three days. Searched lot regarding this issue but not getting any solution.

I have also visited these links [link1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196400/uncaught-exception-thrown-in-shutdown-function) [link2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117955/pdo-exception-error-database-semaphore-doesnot-exist) or duplicate questions

This error is occurring at the time of installation, I am installing `Drupal7` on `linux`

I am using `PostgreSQL 9.4.8` database, php `PHP 5.5.9`

The database user has granted all permissions

following are the exceptions

first exception

```
    Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.

    PDOException: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation &quot;semaphore&quot; does not exist LINE 1: DELETE FROM semaphore ^: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 2108550473576798c2ab0410.91648409 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of /var/www/html/rentspeak/includes/lock.inc).
```

second exception

```
Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation &quot;sessions&quot; does not exist LINE 3: sessions sessions ^: SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {sessions} sessions WHERE ( (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (ssid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; AqE0DsCH1bG6qk3nMspgcEW1J_FUDbF15vNkX5nSdUU [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =&gt; ) in _drupal_session_write() (line 209 of /var/www/html/rentspeak/includes/session.inc).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to setup a fresh Drupal 7.44 with Postgresql and I haven't encountered any issues. The setup went fine. Here are the steps I did.

1. `$ su root` - Switch to root user.
2. `$ su - postgres` - Switch to Postgres user. Note that you need to be `root` first before doing this.
3. `$ createuser --pwprompt --encrypted --no-createrole --no-createdb gerald` - Create a new user called `gerald`.
4. `$ createdb --encoding=UTF8 --owner=gerald drupal` - Create a new database called `drupal`.
5. Run the installation and select the Postgresql type.

Another way to determine the culprit is by reading the logs.

**For Postgresql**

`$ sudo tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log`. In you case it should be `$ sudo tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log`.

**For PHP (if you're using Apache)**

`$ sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

**Additional Troubleshooting**

Also check if there is a problem with `timeout` in PHP. You may want to increase to default timeout settings.

**My stack:**

```
gerald@von-viel ~/ $ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.13
gerald@von-viel ~/ $ php --version
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 (cli) (built: May 19 2016 19:05:57)
```

**Note:** I am using the default configuration of Postgresql.

Hope this helps!