# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: nodes

After I clicked to create a new content type, I got this message.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bis301.cache' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM {cache} WHERE (cid LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE '\') ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => entity_info:% ) in cache_clear_all() (line 168 of C:\xampp\htdocs\bis301\includes\cache.inc).

How can I fix this problem?
Help me please.....

Comment: If the tables of your database are innodb ( drupal default) check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114656/drupal-pdoexception-when-creating-the-tablebase-table-or-view-not-found/114671#114671

Answer (score 0):

Seems that's the problem with the cache table. If you're running localhost. Just drop the existing cache table and recreate it.
Following is the query to create 'cache' table for drupal 7

```
CREATE TABLE `cache` (
 `cid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.',
 `data` longblob COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.',
 `expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or 0 for never.',
 `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry was created.',
 `serialized` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).',
 PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
 KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Generic cache table for caching things not separated out...'
```