# Error 1146 Table doesn't exist checking "drush migrate-status" upgrading

Tags: 8, database, drush, upgrading

I have found the next error when I tried "drush migrate-status" migrating from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.

Drupal 7.53 and Drupal 8.2.5 both with 10.0.28-MariaDB SLE 12 SP1 package.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.filter_formats' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{filter_formats} f) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.i18n_variable' doesn't exist: SELECT v.*
FROM 
{i18n_variable} v
WHERE  (name IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_0)); Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => site_offline_message
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.i18n_variable' doesn't exist: SELECT v.*
FROM 
{i18n_variable} v
WHERE  (name IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_0, :db_condition_placeholder_1, :db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3, :db_condition_placeholder_4, :db_condition_placeholder_5)); Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => site_name
    [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => site_mail
    [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => site_slogan
    [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => site_frontpage
    [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => site_403
    [:db_condition_placeholder_5] => site_404
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.i18n_variable' doesn't exist: SELECT v.*
FROM 
{i18n_variable} v
WHERE  (name IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_0, :db_condition_placeholder_1, :db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3, :db_condition_placeholder_4, :db_condition_placeholder_5, :db_condition_placeholder_6, :db_condition_placeholder_7, :db_condition_placeholder_8, :db_condition_placeholder_9, :db_condition_placeholder_10, :db_condition_placeholder_11, :db_condition_placeholder_12, :db_condition_placeholder_13)); Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => user_mail_status_activated_subject
    [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => user_mail_status_activated_body
    [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => user_mail_password_reset_subject
    [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => user_mail_password_reset_body
    [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => user_mail_status_deleted_subject
    [:db_condition_placeholder_5] => user_mail_status_deleted_body
    [:db_condition_placeholder_6] => user_mail_register_admin_created_subject
    [:db_condition_placeholder_7] => user_mail_register_admin_created_body
    [:db_condition_placeholder_8] => user_mail_register_no_approval_required_subject
    [:db_condition_placeholder_9] => user_mail_register_no_approval_required_body
    [:db_condition_placeholder_10] => user_mail_register_pending_approval_subject
    [:db_condition_placeholder_11] => user_mail_register_pending_approval_body
    [:db_condition_placeholder_12] => user_mail_status_blocked_subject
    [:db_condition_placeholder_13] => user_mail_status_blocked_body
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.i18n_variable' doesn't exist: SELECT v.*
FROM 
{i18n_variable} v
WHERE  (name IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_0, :db_condition_placeholder_1, :db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3, :db_condition_placeholder_4)); Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => user_mail_status_blocked_notify
    [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => user_mail_status_activated_notify
    [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => user_email_verification
    [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => user_register
    [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => anonymous
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.imagecache_preset' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{imagecache_preset} icp) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.boxes' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{boxes} b) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.comment' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{comment} c
INNER JOIN {node} n ON c.nid = n.nid) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.files' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{files} f) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.comments' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{comments} c
INNER JOIN {node} n ON c.nid = n.nid) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.content_node_field' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT cnf.field_name AS field_name, cnf.type AS type, cnf.global_settings AS global_settings, cnf.required AS required, cnf.multiple AS multiple, cnf.db_storage AS db_storage, cnf.module AS module, cnf.db_columns AS db_columns, cnf.active AS active, cnf.locked AS locked, 1 AS expression
FROM 
{content_node_field} cnf
INNER JOIN {content_node_field_instance} cnfi ON cnfi.field_name = cnf.field_name) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.content_node_field_instance' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{content_node_field_instance} cnfi
INNER JOIN {content_node_field} cnf ON cnf.field_name = cnfi.field_name) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.content_node_field_instance' doesn't exist: SELECT cnfi.display_settings AS display_settings
FROM 
{content_node_field_instance} cnfi; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.content_node_field_instance' doesn't exist: SELECT cnfi.field_name AS field_name, cnfi.type_name AS type_name, cnfi.weight AS weight, cnfi.label AS label, cnfi.display_settings AS display_settings, cnfi.widget_settings AS widget_settings, cnf.type AS type, cnf.module AS module
FROM 
{content_node_field_instance} cnfi
INNER JOIN {content_node_field} cnf ON cnfi.field_name = cnf.field_name
ORDER BY cnfi.weight ASC; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.content_node_field_instance' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{content_node_field_instance} cnfi
INNER JOIN {content_node_field} cnf ON cnfi.field_name = cnf.field_name) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.content_group' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{content_group} g) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.content_group' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{content_group} g) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.upload' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT u.nid AS nid, u.vid AS vid, n.type AS type, 1 AS expression
FROM 
{upload} u
INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.nid = u.nid AND n.vid = u.vid) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{vocabulary} v) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{vocabulary} v) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{vocabulary} v
INNER JOIN {vocabulary_node_types} nt ON v.vid = nt.vid) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{vocabulary} v
INNER JOIN {vocabulary_node_types} nt ON v.vid = nt.vid) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{vocabulary} v
INNER JOIN {vocabulary_node_types} nt ON v.vid = nt.vid) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.term_data' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT td.*, 1 AS expression
FROM 
{term_data} td) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.profile_field' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{profile_field} pf) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.profile_field' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{profile_field} pf) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.profile_field' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{profile_field} pf) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.profile_field' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{profile_field} pf) subquery; Array
(
)

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.profile_values' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT pv.uid AS uid, 1 AS expression
FROM 
{profile_values} pv) subquery; Array
(
)

 Group: Default (default)                Status  Total  Imported  Unprocessed  Last imported 
 contact_category                        Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_date_formats                         Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_dblog_settings                       Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_filter_format                        Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_i18n_system_maintenance              Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_i18n_system_site                     Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_i18n_user_mail                       Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_i18n_user_settings                   Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_imagecache_presets                   Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_language_types                       Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_menu                                 Idle    6      0         6                          
 d6_node_settings                        Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_search_settings                      Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_system_cron                          Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_system_date                          Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_system_file                          Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_system_performance                   Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_url_alias                            Idle    615    0         615                        
 d6_user_mail                            Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_user_settings                        Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_dblog_settings                       Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_filter_settings                      Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_global_theme_settings                Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_image_settings                       Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_image_styles                         Idle    5      0         5                          
 d7_language_types                       Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_node_settings                        Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_search_settings                      Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_system_authorize                     Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_system_cron                          Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_system_date                          Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_system_file                          Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_system_mail                          Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_system_performance                   Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_url_alias                            Idle    615    0         615                        
 d7_user_flood                           Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_user_mail                            Idle    1      0         1                          
 file_settings                           Idle    0      0         0                          
 locale_settings                         Idle    0      0         0                          
 menu_settings                           Idle    0      0         0                          
 search_page                             Idle    0      0         0                          
 system_image                            Idle    1      0         1                          
 system_image_gd                         Idle    0      0         0                          
 system_logging                          Idle    0      0         0                          
 system_maintenance                      Idle    0      0         0                          
 system_rss                              Idle    0      0         0                          
 system_site                             Idle    1      0         1                          
 taxonomy_settings                       Idle    0      0         0                          
 text_settings                           Idle    0      0         0                          
 update_settings                         Idle    1      0         1                          
 block_content_type                      Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_menu_links                           Idle    36     0         36                         
 d7_contact_settings                     Idle    1      0         1                          
 block_content_body_field                Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_contact_settings                     Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_custom_block                         Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_user_role                            Idle    4      0         4                          
 d6_block                                Idle    200    0         200                        
 d7_filter_format                        Idle    6      0         6                          
 d7_custom_block                         Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_user_role                            Idle    4      0         4                          
 d7_block                                Idle    200    0         200                        
 d7_node_type                            Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_comment_type                         Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_comment_field                        Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_comment_field_instance               Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_comment_entity_form_display          Idle    7      0         7                          
 d6_comment_type                         Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_comment_field                        Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_node_type                            Idle    7      0         7                          
 d6_comment_field_instance               Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_comment_entity_display               Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_comment_entity_display               Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_file                                 Idle    806    0         806                        
 language                                Idle    2      0         2                          
 default_language                        Idle    1      0         1                          
 user_picture_field                      Idle    1      0         1                          
 user_picture_field_instance             Idle    1      0         1                          
 user_picture_entity_display             Idle    1      0         1                          
 user_picture_entity_form_display        Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_field                                Idle    54     0         54                         
 d7_taxonomy_vocabulary                  Idle    4      0         4                          
 d7_field_instance                       Idle    78     0         78                         
 d7_user                                 Idle    14     0         14                         
 d7_node:article                         Idle    162    0         162                        
 d7_node:ddb_newsletter                  Idle    5      0         5                          
 d7_node:faq                             Idle    33     0         33                         
 d7_node:help                            Idle    14     0         14                         
 d7_node:init_service_article            Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_node:page                            Idle    50     0         50                         
 d7_node:simplenews                      Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_comment                              Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_comment_entity_form_display_subject  Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_comment_entity_form_display_subject  Idle    7      0         7                          
 d6_comment_entity_form_display          Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_file                                 Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_user_picture_file                    Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_user                                 Idle    14     0         14                         
 d6_comment                              Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d7_authmap                              Idle    13     0         13                         
 d6_authmap                              Idle    13     0         13                         
 d6_field                                Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_field_instance                       Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_view_modes                           Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_field_formatter_settings             Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d7_field_instance_widget_settings       Idle    85     0         85                         
 d6_field_instance_widget_settings       Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d7_view_modes                           Idle    18     0         18                         
 d7_field_formatter_settings             Idle    212    0         212                        
 d6_field_group_entity_view_display      Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_field_group_entity_form_display      Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d7_field_group                          Idle    4      0         4                          
 d6_upload_field                         Idle    1      0         1                          
 d6_upload_field_instance                Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_upload                               Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_upload_entity_display                Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_upload_entity_form_display           Idle    0      0         0                          
 language_prefixes_and_domains           Idle    2      0         2                          
 d7_language_negotiation_settings        Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_language_content_settings            Idle    7      0         7                          
 d6_language_negotiation_settings        Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_language_content_settings            Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_node_title_label                     Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_node_revision:article                Idle    611    0         611                        
 d7_node_revision:ddb_newsletter         Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_node_revision:faq                    Idle    76     0         76                         
 d7_node_revision:help                   Idle    90     0         90                         
 d7_node_revision:init_service_article   Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_node_revision:page                   Idle    792    0         792                        
 d7_node_revision:simplenews             Idle    0      0         0                          
 d6_node_setting_sticky                  Idle    7      0         7                          
 d6_node_setting_status                  Idle    7      0         7                          
 d6_node_setting_promote                 Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_shortcut_set                         Idle    1      0         1                          
 d7_menu                                 Idle    6      0         6                          
 d7_menu_links                           Idle    36     0         36                         
 d7_shortcut                             Idle    6      0         6                          
 d7_shortcut_set_users                   Idle    0      0         0                          
 d7_taxonomy_term:newsletter             Idle    2      0         2                          
 d7_taxonomy_term:ddb_faq                Idle    7      0         7                          
 d7_taxonomy_term:article_categories     Idle    5      0         5                          
 d7_taxonomy_term:culture_category       Idle    2      0         2                          
 d6_taxonomy_vocabulary                  Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_vocabulary_field                     Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_vocabulary_field_instance            Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_vocabulary_entity_display            Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_vocabulary_entity_form_display       Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_taxonomy_term                        Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_user_contact_settings                Idle    14     0         14                         
 user_profile_field                      Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 user_profile_field_instance             Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 user_profile_entity_form_display        Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 user_profile_entity_display             Idle    N/A    0         N/A                        
 d6_profile_values                       Idle    N/A    0         N/A
```

It looks like a D7 database problem. I have installed [schema module](https://www.drupal.org/project/schema) to check the database and I see that the database is inconsistent.
I have 6 mismtach in these modules FIELD_SQL_STORAGE, JW_PLAYER, LOCALE, I18N_STRING, ENTITY_TRANSLATION. And 7 extra tables: book, field_data_field_help_additional_content, field_data_field_image, field_data_field_tags, field_revision_field_help_additional_content, field_revision_field_image, field_revision_field_tags.

I have unistalled the modules with Mismatch problems but it doesn't affect to the error message trying to migrate from D7 to D8.

In the *Status Report* page in the D7, after install the schema module appears the message:

```
Some modules have database schema updates to install. You should run the database update script immediately.
```

But going to the page /update.php I get the message of "No pending updates." Event if the message you should update immediately your DB still appear in the status repor page.

Reading another [similars problems](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114656/drupal-pdoexception-when-creating-the-tablebase-table-or-view-not-found), I tried the solution that works for them, I have changed the Engine of my database from InnoDB to MyIsam but didn't affect neither.

Any idea about what more could I try?

Comment: Could you tell us how you started the migration? Have you started with the steps described on https://www.drupal.org/node/2350651 ?